# Optaplanner many to many relationship

Tags: optaplanner

I have been trying to understand the opta planner guidelines for many to many relationship ( eg :  [How to solve many to many relationship using OptaPlanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717109/how-to-solve-many-to-many-relationship-using-optaplanner) , https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2016/10/26/DomainModelingGuide.html)

In my case , the relationship between shift and employees is many to many . While defining the assignment class ,it is advised that we should  know how many employees can be assigned to a shift. 
This is not a constant value in my case. The number of employees needed for the shift depends on the type of the shift. In that case ,how can we specify the constraint ? If there is any example in the tutorial which is addressing this scenario , please let me know

Comment: Does it have a max value? You could always use that. Also, take a look at the nurse rostering example in the OptaPlanner repo.

Comment: yes . It should be feasible to agree upon a max value. In that case , how do we define the max value constraint ?  I was looking into the training example - I will check the nurse roaster as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The employee rostering example already does this. Before the solve() method is called (well, actually in the NurseRosteringImporter already), we create n ShiftAssignments for each Shift instance, depending on the ShiftType of that Shift.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Will go through the nurse roaster example.

Comment: Can you please confirm if the indexInShift  is to restrict the number of employees per shift ?   `NurseRosteringImporter -> createShiftAssignmentList ` Where is this variable used

Comment: Got it - It is one of the rules . Thanks